# Проблема с подключением модуля FS Node.js

Tags: браузер, отладка, плагин

При подключении модуля через require('fs') выдает в консоли:
module is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/fs.js.

Нужно его отдельно устанавливать или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Да, попробуйте его установить вручную

```
npm install file-system --save
```

Comment: То же самое. Хотя теперь модуль установился с версией 2.2.1. А ранее было 0.0.2.

Comment: Windows 7 Starter, AMD

Comment: В папку nodejs/node_modules установилось.

Comment: попробуйте вызвать эту команду из под папки проэкта

Comment: Я думаю, может, неправильный путь указан? Надо require('.../fs'). Что- то тут дописать?

Comment: Да, попробуйте.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977073/firefox-addon-error-module-path-is-not-found-at-resource-gre-modules-common

Answer (score 0):

Fs работает только с node js, чтоб работал в баузерах нужно поднимать веб на node